# How to organise via Custom Fields on Category Page

Tags: custom-field

I have a custom field named: eventdate
The posts are all in the standard post type. 
I want to order by this field ascending. 
I have tried over 15 different solutions but no joy . 
Every post simply gets turned into a list of all posts.

I have tried all solutions both before and after the following.

```
if(have_posts()){
 while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Please help, I have been trying to sort this for at least 14 hours.

Comment: do you want to show all posts which has only meta_key = eventdate in a specific category.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `query_posts` to sort the post by you custom field,
Add this before you loop

```
query_posts( $query_string . 'meta_key=eventdate&order=ASC&orderby=meta_value');
```

Comment: thanks for looking but that just seems to lists all posts in all categories and not the order within categories. Any other idea please?

Comment: this code assumes you are in a category archive if not then just add `&cat=cat_ID` and change `cat_ID` with the actual category id